# Windows Mobile 6 Emulator change storage?

Tags: memory-management, emulation, windows-mobile-6

How do i change the size of the Windows Mobile 6 Emulator. Its fixed at 32mb. I read this post: [Increasing Windows Mobile 5 Emulator Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821720/increasing-windows-mobile-5-emulator-storage)

But it only helps for the 5.0 version. Isnt there any way to increase the storage size in version 6.0?

Comment: Im curious.Why would you want to do this? Is not not best to test your software against the lowest posible phone hardware ?

Comment: @EKS - The question isn't about best practices for writing and testing apps, it's just a question on how to increase memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just answered in the WinMo 5.0 question, but it works for 6.0 too, so I'll repost it:

Under http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=549675 you will find a driver for the emulator that sets up a RAM Disk, that for the emulator is seen as an external storage card but doesn't suffer from the issues with mapping a folder. I've checked with SQL Compact sdf file stored in the RAMDisk and it works like a charm. I've used it as a 64MB drive but supposedly it can handle up to 256 MB.